# How to see the assembly code from a Ansi C hello world written in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ansi-c

I'm playing with Ansi C in visual studio, created the simple Ansi C program (I had to change VS configuration to not use cpp but ansi c)

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;

printf("Hello World! \n\n");

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

I compiled it and it generated this:

[image]

First of all I was expecting a simple .exe and I don't know why this .ilk and .pdb were created but the question here is how can I see the assembly code generated by the compiled c program?

thanks

Comment: What Jerry said. Neither the .ilk nor the .pdb are needed for the exe to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.ilk` is an incremental linking file, which can help speed up linking when you make minor changes to your code, then re-link.

The `.pdb` is a Program database--use when debugging.

To get the assembly language to which your code translates, you can compile with `/Fa`.

Comment: very helpful as always Jerry, can you help me to understand what is the compiler visual studio is calling when I build a ansi c program and how I can add the /Fa or any other argument to it? thanks man.

Comment: @ThePoet: I'd at least consider compiling on the command line. Inside the IDE, right click the file in the solution explorer, choose Properties, then go to C/C++ -> Output Files -> Assembler Output and change from "No Listing" to one of the other options (probably "assembly only" or "assembly with source code").

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Assembler Output` setting in the Project Properties.

You can request that Visual Studio show the assembly code for your compiled program by:

1. Right-clicking on the Project name in the Solution Explorer, and choosing `Properties` from the menu that appears.
2. Using the tree-view menu on the left side of the dialog box that appears, click to `Configuration Properties` > `C/C++` > `Output Files`.
3. Change the value for `Assembler Output` from **`No Listing`** to **`Assembly with Source Code (/FAs)`**
4. Click **OK** to close the dialog box.
5. Rebuild your program.

Now you will have a *project-name*`.asm` file, located in the Debug or Release subdirectory of your project directory.  That is a text file displaying the source code of your program, and the assembly code that each line was converted into.